# Suppress expect output

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, expect

I have the following script which logins to a router and execute command. how can i accomplist only the output and not show anything else.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
set timeout 3000
log_user 0
spawn ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ananair@172.20.60.187
expect {
"*assword:" {
send "anismi@123\n"
expect "*#"
log_user 1
send "show bgp vrf IKA summary | include 10.155.192.50\n"
expect "*#"
}
}
```

This is the output of the above script.

```
[root@cap-nwmon-01 anand]# ./migrate.sh
show bgp vrf IKA summary | include 10.155.192.50
Sun Feb 25 07:17:25.150 EET
10.155.192.50     0 65256 3107179 4237248  1624156    0    0    5d17h        322
```

This is the only output i want from this script.

```
Sun Feb 25 07:17:25.150 EET
10.155.192.50     0 65256 3107179 4237248  1624156    0    0    5d17h        322
```

Comment: What about `expect /the/script.exp | tail -n 2`?

Comment: this is useful but doesnt work for me.. as i have more output coming in the code above for other devices.

Comment: Please update your question to tell your real requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You see the extra line because you gave the command `log_user 1` before `send "show..."`, which causes the echo of `"show..."` to be logged to the stdout.  If you move this command one line later, after the `send`, and also wait for the echo to complete by adding an `expect "\n"`, then you will see less:

```
expect "#"
send "show bgp vrf IKA summary | include 10.155.192.50\n"
expect "\n"
log_user 1
expect "#"
```

Note, the `*` glob character at the start of a pattern serves no purpose.

Alternatively, instead of changing `log_user` you should look at using variable `$expect_out(buffer)` which holds what matched up to the pattern, inclusive.

Comment: Thanks this cleared the send command from the output.. But it shows the hostname of the device on which the command is run. at the last line
`RP/0/RSP0/CPU0:cap-s12a-core-rtr1#[root@cap-nwmon-01 anand]#`

Comment: Since you only want to look at the first 2 lines of the reply, and not the command prompt `#`, you can replace the `expect "#"` that looks for the prompt by, for example, `expect -gl "\n*\n"`, that is two newlines. (The `-gl` option is to ensure expect understands the string is a glob pattern, because strings with `\n` can be misinterpreted in this context).

Comment: one more doubt.. suppose my output has 3 lines how do i write the expect -gl

Comment: Add another `*\n` to match any characters then a newline: `expect -gl "\n*\n*\n"`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to redirect the unwanted output like

`send "show bgp vrf IKA summary | include 10.155.192.50\n" &> /dev/null`

Redirecting it's stdout and stderr to the nothingness of oblivion

Comment: Expect does not understand `&> /dev/null`.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
        if {[string match -nocase *password* $prompt]} {
            log_user 0
        } else {
            log_user 1
        }
        send -- "$answer\r"
        if {[string match -nocase *password* $prompt]} {
            expect "\n"
            log_user 1
            puts "\n"
        }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).